# Image gets Rotated when using with img tag in React; Looks fine when opened with windows viewer

Tags: reactjs, image, dslr

I have an image that I want to render using  in react, but for some reason the image get rotated but when I open the image in mspaint and resave with no edits, it seems to render fine in react

Link to img: [img link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rdM2ubSQAALNrLlZo3TWmMzsQproUK95)

Here is the link that can be used directly in the img tag's src:

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1rdM2ubSQAALNrLlZo3TWmMzsQproUK95

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JPEg Autorotate ([link](https://savolai.net/software/jpeg-autorotate/)) windows tool to fix all the images. Although I also see they have a ([npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jpeg-autorotate)) to do the same which I didnt try. FYI, these images were taken from a DSLR camera. I also read images taken from a lot smart phones have the similar issue. And google photos and other tools fix these issues before rendering hence it looks fine.